# Configuring antispam email gateway with mailscanner and postfix as relay server

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, centos7, mailscanner

I have configured mailscanner and postfix to receive emails, scan it using clamAV and forward it to a mail server inside my network.

**internet<---->mail.abc.com(MailScanner)<----->mail1.abc.com(Dest. Email Server)**

Till now i'am able to receive email from outside to my antispam gateway, scan it and forward it to internal postfix server. But on internal postfix i'm getting an error.

> **May 13 01:25:34 mail1 postfix/smtpd[18995]: connect from unknown[10.100.1.1] May 13 01:25:34 mail1 postfix/smtpd[18995]:
>   NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[10.100.1.1]: 454 4.7.1
>   : Relay access denied;
>   from= to= proto=ESMTP
>   helo= May 13 01:25:34 mail1 postfix/smtpd[18995]:
>   disconnect from unknown[10.100.1.1]
>   **

10.100.1.1 is the ip for gateway relay server and 10.100.1.100 is the internal email server i.e. destination mail server.

**transport file**

abc.com smtp:[10.100.1.100]

Also do i need to add smtp credentials on gateway server to able to forward all emails of abc.com to internal mail server? if yes.. how?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be precise as you didn't provide any configuration of either server, but in general:

- Your external filter server should have knowledge of the existing addresses in order to be able to reject mail to non-existing addresses. For this, you can use [`relay_recipient_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_recipient_maps).
- The internal mail server doesn't need to *relay* anything at all (for the filter server) as it should have all the mailboxes in [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) or within a [Virtual Domain](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html).

Comment: So gateway server should have list of all users accounts that are on end destination server.?? how can i sync those usernames??
sorry i'm noob in mail servers..

Comment: `relay_recipient_maps` has similar format to `virtual_alias_maps`, so in easiest case you can just copy that file.